# Trying to get first letter from first name in nawk script to html

Tags: unix, nawk

Why is line 17 not working (commented in code)?:

```
#!/bin/nawk -f

BEGIN {
    print "<html>"
    print "<body>"
    print "  <table border=2>"
    print "    <tr>"
    print "      <th>Name</th>"              
    print "      <th>Username</th>"              
    print "      <th>Email</th>"                    
    print "    </tr>"
}

{
    print "    <tr>"
    print "      <td>" $2 " " $1"</td>"                   
    print "      <td>"'{Substr($1,1,1)}' "</td>"  ###### Line 17                 
is
    print "      <td>" $3 "</td>"
```

Am I allowed to put a statement like that in line 17?  Im trying to get the first letter of the first name.

Comment: `substr` in lowercase?

Comment: Yes, I need to throw a toLower in there as well

Comment: Yes, but I mean that the function is `substr`, not `Substr` (as far as I am concerned).

Comment: is that why its not working?

Comment: Check it! Could be one reason

Comment: Although the expressions I usually use are kind of `printf ("hello %s bye", tolower($1))`, not in between the strings.

Comment: get following stErr: /bin/nawk: syntax error at source line 17
 context is
            print "     <td>" >>>  ' <<< substr($1,1,1)}' "</td>"                   ###Change this
/bin/nawk: illegal statement at source line 17
/bin/nawk: extra } at source line 20
        extra }

Comment: Im actually trying to pull the first letter of the first name and add it to the beginning of the last name to create the username.  I need to do the tolower as well; can do to lower. Just trying to figure how to put my statement in line 17 for the user name.  Am I missing brackets or something?  this is the first time trying to append text to html using nawk

Comment: what does this stErr mean:   context is
            print "     <td>" >>>  { <<<  'substr($1,1,1)}' "</td>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes in this line should be removed. Currently the quoting allows the shell to parse Substr and you do not want that to happen.

Also the command is substr not Substr.

```
print "      <td>"'{Substr($1,1,1)}' "</td>"  ###### Line 17
```

change to-:

```
print "      <td>" substr($1,1,1) "</td>"
```

Comment: Gosh, Im an idiot.  Ive been hitting shift + insert with the wrong statement in my copy bin the whole time.  Im an idiot (not really, just burnt out)  been writing this and SQL statement for past 10 hours.  LOL.  Thank you for your help.  I figured it out.

Comment: One thing though, Ive unset noclobber and when I run the following statemetn: mk_html.awk sample.txt > mysample.html  It keeps saying mysample.html arlready exists in the stError.  Why is this?

Comment: turn off noclobber with `set +o noclobber`. Or better use `>|` e.g. `mk_html.awk sample.txt >| mysample.html` to force overwrite.